# Добавить GET переменную по клику в URL

Tags: javascript

Есть код, он добавляет отпечаток в форму регистрации:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() { 
  new Fingerprint2().get(function(result, components){
      var input = document.createElement('input');
      input.type = 'hidden';
      input.name = 'fgpr';
      input.value = result;
      document.forms['regform'].appendChild(input);
  });
}, false);
```

Есть также группа ссылок

```
<div id="social_gr">
    <a href="{$fsbk_lnk}" class="btn_fb">войти</a>
    <a href="{$vkon_lnk}" class="btn_vk">войти</a>
</div>
```

Необходимо при клике на ссылку в этой группе динамически "приклеивать" отпечаток (Т.е. значение, которое присваивается input-у: input.value = result) в виде GET параметра в конец текущей ссылки. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы решить вашу большую сложную задачу, нужно решить несколько маленьких простых задач:

1. Назначить обработчик события `click` на ссылках в группе `#social_gr`

   ```
   var links = document.getElementById('social_gr').getElementsByTagName('a');

   for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
     links[i].addEventListener('click', onclick, false);
   }
   ```
2. Добавить параметр к ссылке

   ```
   // link - это элемент `a`

   if (link.href.indexOf('?') === -1) {
     // если в ссылке не содержатся другие параметры
     link.href += '?fgpr=' + getFingerprint();
   } else {
     // если в ссылке уже содержатся другие параметры
     link.href += '&fgpr=' + getFingerprint();  
   }
   ```

   Или укороченная запись с использованием тернарного оператора

   ```
   link.href += (link.href.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&') + 'fgpr=' + getFingerprint();
   ```
3. Получить значение отпечатка из `input`

   ```
   var fingerprint = document.getElementsByName('fgpr')[0].value;
   ```

---

Полный рабочий код примера на [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwOEwM)

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить с помощью history без перезагрузки страницы

```js
history.pushState({}, document.title, window.location.href + '?test=1')
```